# Not able to select an option from drop down selection in Playwright?

Tags: c#, webautomation, playwright, playwright-sharp

I'm trying to fill in an online account creation form. But there is a drop down option thats not a normal select element. Please help sorry if its something easy am new to c#.

```
public static async Task Main()
    {
        using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
        var chromium = playwright.Chromium;
        var browser = await chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions {Headless = false}); 
        
        Console.WriteLine(browser.IsConnected);
        var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
        await page.GotoAsync("https://www.slamjam.com/en_SG/login?action=register");
        await page.SelectOptionAsync("xpath=/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/span/span[1]/span", new SelectOptionValue { Label = "Mr." });
        await page.FillAsync("id=registration-form-fname", "belinda");
        await page.FillAsync("id=registration-form-lname", "Yeo");
        await page.FillAsync("id=registration-form-birthday", "17/12/1990");
        await page.FillAsync("id=registration-form-email", "email");
        await page.FillAsync("id=registration-form-email-confirm", "email");
        await page.FillAsync("id=registration-form-password", "PW");
        await page.FillAsync("id=registration-form-password-confirm", "PW");
        await page.CheckAsync("xpath=/ html / body / div[1] / main / div / div / div / div / form / div[9] / label");
        await page.CheckAsync("xpath=/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div/div/div/form/div[11]/label");
        await page.ClickAsync("id=validationCaptchaRegistration");
    }
```

If you see I tried using the select option function in Playwright but to no avail.

Here is the site https://www.slamjam.com/en_SG/login?action=register

Comment: The select on that page is not a native select (`<select>`) its a custom one. So in your case you would need to click first on it and then on the actual item. I'd suggest to use Playwright's codegen which should help you to create good selectors: https://playwright.dev/docs/cli#generate-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Max's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69273143/not-able-to-select-an-option-from-drop-down-selection-in-playwright/70098823#comment122442256_69273143), the issue is that the `select` element isn't actually a normal HTML `select` element. It's just a `span` that displays the list of options underneath it when clicked.

You can do something like this:

```
await page.ClickAsync("id=select2-registration-form-title-container");
await page.ClickAsync("li:has-text('Mr.'):visible");
```

Only use IDs if you're fairly sure they won't be changing. Normally, it's [best to use attributes that are visible to the user](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/selectors/#best-practices) as they're less likely to change.